# c++ accessing parent widgets from a function

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to C++ and Qt and I am trying to access a widget from a parent class.

Here is my mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent )
    : QMainWindow( parent )
    , ui( new Ui::MainWindow ) 
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

I have another class, and I am trying to access a widget from "ui" in that class. Like so:

```
DashBoard::DashBoard( MainWindow *parent ) : QObject( parent ) 
{
}

void DashBoard::select(  ) 
{
    parent->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```

This gives me an error saying that the methods and fields could not be resolved. But when I put the line `parent->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);` in the constructor, there is no problem.

Would someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: You should rather emit a signal in your `DashBoard::select()` function and connect it either to your `menSL` object's `setCurrentIndex(int)` slot, or to a function in your `MainWindow` class.

Comment: I agree with thuga. Emitting a signal from DashBoard is a better approach.

Comment: I would not recommend to access `ui` of your parent directly. Instead derive your parent from an interface with defined accessor methods that can be called from your child. Example call: dynamic_cast<MyWidgetAccessorInterface*>(parent())->SetMenu(0); Or use signal/slot concept.

Comment: @thuga would you mind giving me an example of that, please?

Comment: @user2444217 [This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) should help you out. Basically you declare a signal in your `dashboard.h`. Then in your class that creates a `Dashboard` object (i'm assuming this is your `MainWindow` class), you connect your signal to a slot. Something like: `connect(dashBoard, SIGNAL(mySignal(int)), ui->menuSL, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));`

Answer (score 3):

From the code one can infer that the class `DashBoard` inherits `QObject`. The `parent` field of a `QObject` is defined as a pointer to a `QObject` so when you call `parent->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);` inside a method of the class `DashBoard` you're assuming that `QObject` defines a member called `ui` which is not true.

Just cast parent this way:

```
((MainWindow*)(parent()))->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

or this one:

```
MainWindow* parent = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent());
// check parent is not null
parent->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

In the constructor you don't see the error because `parent` is defined as a pointer to an object of the class `MainWindow` and then passed to the `QObject`'s constructor.

Don't forget to make `ui` public and to include the auto generated UI header if using Qt Designer (in your case probably `"ui_mainwindow.h"`) in the `DashBoard` cpp file.

NOTE: I'm just trying to answer your question but I encourage you to review the way you're doing this. There are several ways of achieving the same with a more consistent OO design.

Comment: that produces this
error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

Comment: Make `ui` public and include `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in the DashBoard cpp.

Comment: `((MainWindow*)(parent()))->...` actually works, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @TranslucentCloud , your solution worked for me too!

Comment: It's not mine, it's in the answer, but anyway, welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Within your select method, you try to use a variable named `parent`. But you need the `QObject::parent()` method.

Furthermore, you need to cast the parent to `QMainWindow`.

```
void DashBoard::select(  ) {
  QMainWindow* parent = qobject_cast<QMainWindow>(this->parent());
  if (parent == 0) { return; } // or some other error handling
  parent->ui->menuSL->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```

You can only access `ui` if it is public.

**At all, I think you should provide a method within you `MainWindow` class which does the operation you want.**

Comment: I don't know, isn't casting return of parent() to the right class kind of defeats the purpose of like not overriding parent() to begin with?